# how to get the value of index and show it in input text

Tags: jquery

I am having one issue i am trying to get the each value of the index and i want to show it seperately on each input box but i stuck somewhere in my code and i am not getting in actually how to seperate all these value using jquery. I need help !

Here is my code :-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>My table</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $('.studtbl tr').click(function(){

                $(this).css({"background":"#f2f2f2"});
                alert($(this).text());
                $(this).find("td").each(function(index,i){


                     console.log( index+ ": " + $( this ).text() );
                     //console.log($(this).get(0).val('0'));
                     console.log("------------------");
                     console.log(i);

                     i++;

                });
            })
            console.log(myarray.val);
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<table border="1">
<tr>
            <td><input type="text" id="name"></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="email"></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="age"></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="gender"></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="height"></td>
</tr>   
</table>
    <table border="1" class="studtbl">
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Gender</th>
            <th>Height</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>pqr</td>
            <td>pqr@gmal.com</td>
            <td>21</td>
            <td>M</td>
            <td>6 feet</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>abc</td>
            <td>abc@gmal.com</td>
            <td>23</td>
            <td>M</td>
            <td>5 feet 7 inches</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>xyz</td>
            <td>xyz@gmal.com</td>
            <td>27</td>
            <td>M</td>
            <td>5 feet 9 inches</td>
        </tr>



    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to all the value at index position seperately on each input box with the id as name , email, age, gender, height.

Comment: Pranay Do you still have problems ?

Comment: yes it solves my issues but i have to update the value in the table accordingly i do not know how to update the values in the table according to those input fields not getting actually how to fetch and update the same row that is clicked..!!!!

Comment: Please take a look at my snippet now. I've updated it. I've changed both your HTML and jquery. If you have more question you have to make a new question here. you can't keep changing the question when you run into another problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$("table input").eq(index).val($(this).text())` to inser the value into each input field.

`$("table input").eq(index)` takes the input equal the current `td` that we loop through.

You can try this in the example below.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.studtbl tr').click(function() {
    if ($(this).index() > 1) {

      $(this).css({
        "background": "#f2f2f2"
      });
      $(this).find("td").each(function(index, i) {

        $("table input").eq(index).val($(this).text())
        $("table tr:eq(0) button").attr("data-row", $('.studtbl tr').index($(this).closest('tr')));

      });
    }
  })

});

$('.save').click(function() {
  var row = $(this).attr("data-row");
  $('.studtbl tr td input').each(function(index, i) {
    $('.studtbl tr:eq(' + row + ') td').eq(index).text($(i).val())
  })
})
```

```css
input {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table border="1" class="studtbl">
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" id="name"></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="email"></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="age"></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="gender"></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="height"></td>
    <td><button class="save">save</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Age</th>
    <th>Gender</th>
    <th>Height</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>pqr</td>
    <td>pqr@gmal.com</td>
    <td>21</td>
    <td>M</td>
    <td>6 feet</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>abc</td>
    <td>abc@gmal.com</td>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>M</td>
    <td>5 feet 7 inches</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>xyz</td>
    <td>xyz@gmal.com</td>
    <td>27</td>
    <td>M</td>
    <td>5 feet 9 inches</td>
  </tr>



</table>
```

Comment: HI Carsten i think something wrong when i click on the input fields at the top it clears all the input fields...!!

Comment: @PranaySute Updated, If this solved the current problem you should mark this as answer so others with a similar problem knows that this helped you

Comment: Carsten  i write all your code in my editor and do exactly the same but the code is not running in my browser it is working fine here in snippet code but not in the browser..!!

Comment: That i cant help you without more information. You should create another question here on the site and about that. since this is something else than this question

Comment: okay Carsten i would try from my end to find what is going wrong or else i will generate the question but thanks a lot your code helps me ..!!

Comment: @PranaySute No problem, happy to help, remember if this solved your original question then please consider it as an answer and mark it.